# Counting specific cells in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a table like this:

[image: Table view]

The `RP Type` column specifies the type of rate plan which can be (low, high, normal)

I want to create a view in which I can see number of each subscribers' which can be high, normal, low.

It should be like this I guess:

```
Create view t as 
   select 
       SubID, 
       Count(something) as NumeOfHIGH, 
       Count(Something) as NumOfLOW,
       Count(Something) as NumOfNormal
   Group by SubID
```

I might be wrong..Thank you

Comment: You would definitely need a `FROM dbo.YourTableName` in your view definition ....

Comment: @marc_s  :D yes..I knew that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can form your query in the following way:

```
SELECT SubID,
    SUM (
        CASE 
            WHEN RP_Type='High' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 END
    ) AS NumOfHigh,
    SUM (
        CASE 
            WHEN RP_Type='Low' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 END
    ) AS NumOfLow,
    SUM (
        CASE 
            WHEN RP_Type='Normal' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 END
    ) AS NumOfNormal
FROM 
    <table_name>
Group by SubID
```

If there are multiple `RP_Type` in each of High, Low and Normal Category, you can include each type with `WHEN` in respective category.

For more information and reference: [Conditional Processing using CASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213265%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

i tried this :

```
            select  SubscriberID
           ,COUNT(*) AS NumOfPlans
           ,SUM([SP active days]) as ActiveDays
           ,SUM(Case when [RP Type]='low' then 1 else 0 end ) as #LowPlan 
           ,SUM(Case when [RP Type]='high' then 1 else 0 end ) as #NormalPlan
           ,SUM(Case when [RP Type]='high' then 1 else 0 end ) as #HighPlan
           ,SUM(Case when [RP Type]='promotion' then 1 else 0 end ) as #PromotionsPlan
           ,SUM(Case when [RP Type]='portal' then 1 else 0 end ) as #PortablePlan
           ,SUM(Case when [RP Type]='newyear' then 1 else 0 end ) as #NewYearPlan
           ,SUM(Case when [RP Type]='hamaval1' then 1 else 0 end ) as #HamrahAval1Plan
           ,SUM(Case when [RP Type]='hamaval2' then 1 else 0 end ) as #HamrahAval2Plan
           ,SUM(Case when [RP Type]='samsung' then 1 else 0 end ) as #SamsungPlan
           ,SUM(Case when [RP Type]='DEMO' then 1 else 0 end ) as #DemoPlan
           ,SUM(Case when [RP Type]IS null then 1 else 0 end ) as #NuLL
           ,SUM([Extra Quota]) as SumGIG
           from [Cus Consumption].[dbo].CustData
           where [Expiry Date]<= '2014 - 01 - 15'
           group by [SubscriberID]
```

The ironic thing is that i does not return a correct answer..I don't know why @Rohit Aggrawal

Answer (score -1):

is this helpful?

```
   Create view t as 
       select From [tableName]
           [Rp Type],count(*) as NumberOfSubscribers
       Group by [Rp Type]
```

This gives you Number of subscribers in each type, and type

Hope this helpful